# React Native: Pod install leads to different versions in podfile.lock than package.json

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I just did a clean clone of my repo, did `npm install` and then `pod install` in the `ios/` directory. This leads to a change in my `Podfile.lock`, which seemed to have upgraded a couple of modules to a newer version than what is specified in the `package.json` for that corresponding module, for example:

Podfile.lock:

```
-  - react-native-webview (8.1.0):
+  - react-native-webview (8.2.1):
```

package.json:

```
"react-native-webview": "^8.1.0",
```

I would like to understand why this happens and whether this is a problem. I would avoid this but I can't do `npm run ios`, because it says that there are version issues and I have to run `pod install`.

Comment: I am also having same trouble, versions are not syncing between package.json and Podfile.lock. Did you find any solution yet ?

Answer (score 2):

The magic character is `^`:

> “Compatible with version”, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <2.0.0.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/8118803) for further details.

---

In your `package.json` it is defined that your project uses for `react-native-webview` at least version `8.1.0` and less than `9.0.0`.

So if you would check your `package-lock.json` file (or `yarn.lock`), then most probably the version of `react-native-webview` would be `8.2.1` as well.

The versions of `podfile.lock` and `package-lock.json` don't differ.

---

If you really want to have THAT version you specified in the `package.json`, then the third step of the suggested answer of [Maycon Mesquita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60957635/8118803) is correct. Pin the version without the `^`.

Answer (score 1):

When i get deep issues with Podfile/package.json, i do something like that:

1. Delete `./node_modules`;
2. Delete `package-lock.json` and `Podfile.lock`;
3. Set a fixed version to component: "`^8.1.0`" -> "`8.1.0`" [w/o ^];
4. Do the `npm install` then `pod install`.

Comment: I dont want to use step 3. It should have worked without a fixed version. But its not working.